# Why Return Base Method With Blazor OnInitialized Method

Tags: c#, blazor

I am seeing more and more examples of OnInitialized and OnInitializedAsync() returning base.OnInitialized[Async]. But Why?  The examples on the Microsoft website [do not](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-disposal-with-idisposable) include returning the base method

```
protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Contact = new();
    return base.OnInitializedAsync();
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the only overridable lifecycle method where you might need to call base implementation is SetParametersAsync.  Otherwise, its just good practice to call base implementation of overridable methods when inheriting, even if you know current base implementation does nothing.  If you slip a custom base class in between the Blazor base component and your derived component (e.g. a reusable component base class that does some common stuff for you on initialization) then you'd then have to go through all your derived components and add await base.OnInitializedAsync() to reuse that behaviour.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-parameters-are-set-setparametersasync

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It isn't required and you shouldn't add them, just to avoid clutter.

Those life-cycle methods are all virtual empty methods. They are for all intents and purposes abstract but declaring them as such would have required you to override all of them.

Except of course when [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle?view=aspnetcore-5.0#when-parameters-are-set-setparametersasync) otherwise, as with SetParametersAsync. But there the choice of whether and where you call the base implementation is very much part of your logic, see the *"If base.SetParametersAsync isn't invoked"* part.

Answer (score 5):

As this question is referred from elsewhere, for reference here's what the `ComponentBase` methods look like:

```
    protected virtual void OnInitialized()
    {
    }

    protected virtual Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void OnParametersSet()
    {
    }

    protected virtual Task OnParametersSetAsync()
        => Task.CompletedTask;

    protected virtual void OnAfterRender(bool firstRender)
    {
    }

    protected virtual Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
        => Task.CompletedTask;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @neil-w mentioned, your razor component may inherit another custom component, so in this case if a custom component does something in `OnInitialized` or in `OnInitializedAsync` you will broke the logic if you don't call these methods. So, it costs to add base methods calling to avoid possible errors. Also, the right way is to call a creation methods logic in the beginning, and a destruction logic in the end of your function. 
So, the correct code from your example will be:

```cs
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    await base.OnInitializedAsync();
    Contact = new();
}
```